# Unity Set position of GUI element relative to another element that is on a different canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to position a tooltip to be directly below an icon. The structure is:

```
Main Canvas
- Panel
 - UI Element
Tooltip Canvas
- Tooltip Icon
```

When mousing over an icon, I'm attempting to set the position of the tooltip to be just under the ui element. How does one get the absolute position of the ui element?

So far I've tried both

```
float absolute_x = icon.position.x;
or
float absolute_x = icon.anchoredPosition.x;
```

which only wield the relative position to the main canvas,  not the absolute position on the UI.

Comment: you don't, you get the position of the mouse.

Comment: I'd like to position below the icon, where the x is the center point of the icon and the y is the icon - (height / 2) + some_offset though. Getting the mouse means I'd just position it at the mouse.

Comment: I understand.  The mouse positioning thing just seems more industry standard.

Comment: Sure but I'm looking to make it different in my game

Answer (score 2):

First get the Rectransform

```
public RectTransform UIElement;
```

then get position relative to the parent canvas

```
UIElement.localPosition.y
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I finally made a responsive solution to my similar problem.
I wanted to offset an UI element based of the target (UI element too) height so I did 
myUIElement.position = target.position then
myUIElement.localPosition += new Vector3(0, target.rect.heigth, 0)
it works because target.rect returns a localPosition and target.position returns a worldspace position

Comment: This is the way